# ¿Cómo puedo enviar una imagen desde Xamarin forms Android y recibirla en una página Web C# ASP.NET core MVC y guardarla?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Estoy intentando enviar una imagen desde Xamarin forms Android con el siguiente código.

```
var file = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
                if (file == null) return;
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StreamContent(await file.OpenReadAsync()), "file", file.FileName);

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            String url = "http://url.com/imagenes/";
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

            
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("", content);
            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "SUBIDA EXITOSA";
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "SUBIDA FALLIDA";
            }
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo recibirla del lado del servidor para guardarla en la carpeta imagenes que se encuentra en una página web C# ASP.NET core MVC.

Por cierto, del lado de C# ASP.NET core MVC he intentado lo siguiente aunque me dice que "Current" ya no existe en httpcontext, entiendo que debe ser por la versión 6.0 .NET que estoy utilizando:

```
[Route("api/Files/Upload")]
    public async Task<string> Post()
    {
        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName);
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                    return "/Uploads/" + fileName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.Message;
        }
        return "no files";
    }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Tienes que crear un endpoint que reciba el archivo y lo guarde... Por cierto, qué has intentado del lado de MVC?

Comment: ahí agregué lo que uso del lado del MVC. Y al endpoit a que te referis exactamente? Soy nuevo con esto de xamarin

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que la imagen/archivo está llegando adecuadamente al servidor y el problema está en guardar el archivo:

```
[Route("api/Files/Upload")]
public async Task<string> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    try
    {
        
        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {                    
                var fileName = formFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uploads", fileName);
                // O también:
                // var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/Uploads", fileName);
                using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                 }
                return "/Uploads/" + fileName;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return exception.Message;
    }
    return "no files";
}
```

Lectura recomendada: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario! okey, ya no me genera problema en esa linea. Y en la linea de "var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;" como podría solucionar eso? porque ahí también me tira el error

Comment: ¿Comentario? Es una respuesta. Aquí tienes la respuesta actualizada. Saludos.