# ¿Cómo enviar una imagen mediante Xamarin.Forms Android y recibirla en una Web C# ASP.NET core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Estoy intentando enviar una imagen desde xamarin forms en android con el siguiente código

```
 var file = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
            if (file == null) return;
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(new StreamContent(await file.OpenReadAsync()), "file", file.FileName);


            
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            String url = "http://urlDeLaPagina/Imagenes/";
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("", content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "SUBIDA EXITOSA";
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "SUBIDA FALLIDA";
            }
```

Y estoy intentando recibirla desde C# ASP.NET core MVC en un controlador de la siguiente forma:

```
[Route("api/Files/Upload")]
    public async Task<string> Post()
    {
        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName);
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                    return "/Uploads/" + fileName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.Message;
        }
        return "no files";
    }
```

Sin embargo no entiendo bien cómo debería hacer para que la tome el controlador y poder guardarla en la carpeta imagenes. Ya que cuando hago el post me tira la siguiente excepción: "Unable to resolve host "urlDeLaPagina": No address associated with hostname".
Por otro lado la aplicación me tira que httcontext no contiene "Current", entiendo que puede estar deprecado ya que estoy utilizando la versión 6.0 de .NET

En resumen mis problemas serían:

1. ¿Cómo puedo pasar la imagen hacia el controlador y guardarla en la carpeta imagenes?
2. ¿Qué solución le puedo dar a HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName); para que funcione?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo enviar una imagen desde Xamarin forms Android y recibirla en una página Web C# ASP.NET core MVC y guardarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/548520/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-enviar-una-imagen-desde-xamarin-forms-android-y-recibirla-en-una-p%c3%a1g)